# How to add checkbox to custom Listview?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am receiving data from firebase database in a custom ListView. Now what I want is to add a checkbox to that ListView. I have added the checkbox to listview but it is giving me an error. So please anyone help me. Here is my code.

```
    public class AttendanceList extends ArrayAdapter<AttendanceSheetItems> {
private Activity context;
private List<AttendanceSheetItems> attendanceList;

public AttendanceList (Activity context,List<AttendanceSheetItems> attendanceList){

    super(context,R.layout.attendance_sheet,attendanceList);
    this.context=context;
    this.attendanceList=attendanceList;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {



    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        assert vi != null;
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.attendance_sheet, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.rollno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewroll);

        holder.name1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);

       holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
                AttendanceSheetItems attendanceSheetItems = (AttendanceSheetItems) cb.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
                                " is " + cb.isChecked(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                attendanceSheetItems.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
           }
        });
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    AttendanceSheetItems attendanceSheetItems = attendanceList.get(position);
    holder.rollno.setText( attendanceSheetItems.getRollno() );
    holder.name1.setText(attendanceSheetItems.getName());
    holder.name.setChecked(attendanceSheetItems.getChecked());
    holder.name.setTag(attendanceSheetItems);

    return convertView;
```

This is my model class.

```
    public class AttendanceSheetItems {
String rollno;
String name;
Boolean Checked=false;

public AttendanceSheetItems(String rollno, String name, Boolean checked) {
    this.rollno = rollno;
    this.name = name;
  Checked = checked;
}

public String getRollno() {
    return rollno;
}

public void setRollno(String rollno) {
    this.rollno = rollno;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
} public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
   Checked = checked;}
public Boolean getChecked() {

  return Checked; }
```

Here I am receiving data from Firebase database.

```
         public class TakeAttendance extends Activity {
 Spinner clas;
 Button ok,submit;
 EditText date;
 ListView lv;
 DatabaseReference reff;
List<AttendanceSheetItems> attendanceList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_attendance);
    clas = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sclas);
    ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
     submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    date=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvv);
    attendanceList = new ArrayList<>();

    reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Students");
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

          String searchText = clas.getSelectedItem().toString();
           final Query firebaseSearchQuery = reff.orderByChild("clas").equalTo(searchText);
           firebaseSearchQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
              public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                   attendanceList.clear();
                   for (DataSnapshot artistSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                      AttendanceSheetItems attendanceSheetItems = artistSnapshot.getValue(AttendanceSheetItems.class);
                     attendanceList.add(attendanceSheetItems);
     }

             AttendanceList adapter = new AttendanceList(TakeAttendance.this, attendanceList);
                   lv.setAdapter(adapter);

     }

               @Override
              public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
          });
}}
    );}}
```

here is stack trace.

```
    11-09 14:32:28.717 18321-18321/com.example.sanakhan.attendapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sanakhan.attendapp, PID: 18321
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: checked
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzae(Unknown Source:48)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.<init>(Unknown Source:303)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source:12)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source:180)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
    at com.example.sanakhan.attendapp.TakeAttendance$1$1.onDataChange(TakeAttendance.java:53)
    at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source:13)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source:71)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6600)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:518)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:821)
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: My app gets crashed when I click on ok button.

Comment: @malmling please read my code and then tell me where is the problem.

Comment: Provide the stacktrace please. And please reformat your code that it's more readable and add some more explanation.

Comment: I have provided stack trace please see my edited question.

Comment: what is there on `TakeAttendance.java:53`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fix the naming convention, following the java naming convention, the attribure `Boolean Checked=false` should be lowercased : `Boolean Checked=false`and the getter and setter should be  `getChecked()`  `setChecked()`

I hope this helps

Comment: It's working. Thank you.